# How to do form Validation, I want to enable submit button when all the input is filled otherwise its should be disabled

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, validation, bootstrap-modal

[image]

As you can see the send offer button is disabled, I only want the button enabled after both input boxes are filled.

Here, I am sharing my code base with you.

Please go through the code and modify it on stackblitz

**1. example-dialog.component.html**

```
<form id="bidForm" #bidForm="ngForm">
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="inputQuantity">Quantity</label>
      <input
        type="number"
        name="quantity"
        class="form-control"
        id="inputQuantity"
        placeholder="Quantity(QTL)*"
        required
      />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="inputPrice">Price</label>
      <input
        type="number"
        class="form-control"
        id="inputPrice"
        placeholder="Price(₹/QTL)"
        required
      />
    </div>
  </div>

  <button
    type="submit"
    class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"
    [disabled]="!bidForm.form.valid"
  >
    Send offer
  </button>
</form>
```

**2. example-dialog.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Inject, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from "@angular/material/dialog";;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-example-dialog',
  templateUrl: 'example-dialog.component.html',
})
export class ExampleDialogComponent {

  ngOnInit() {

  }


  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ExampleDialogComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) { }


  onNoClick(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Angular has a `FormBuilder` which you can use to make things more pretty and dynamic. Its a paty of a [ReactiveFormsModule](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms), check it out. You can add validation with `Validators.required` to a control and then check the validity of group on the button

EDIT (example added):

Basic usage:

```
 bidForm: FormGroup;
 constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { this.createForm() }
 
 private createForm() {
     this.bidForm = this.fb({
         // You can use multiple validators here
         quantity: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
         inputPrice: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required])
     })
 }
```

and in html like

```
<form [formGroup]="bidForm"
      (ngSubmit)="bidForm.valid && submit()">
 <input type="number"
    formControlName="quantity"
    name="quantity"
    class="form-control"
    id="inputQuantity"
    placeholder="Quantity(QTL)*"/>
  
    /.../

    <button type="submit"
        class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"
        [disabled]="bidForm.invalid">
       Send offer
    </button>

</form>
```

Comment: I voted your answer up, but your answer is close to be a comment. Please add more value to your answer e.g. by an example.

Comment: can you please illustrate the example on stackblitz

Answer (score 0):

This feature can be implemented using Reactive form module easily.  The reactive form has validation named required. This required validation makes your form invalid until your form is filled with the required information.
first, you have to import reactive form module in app.module.ts

```js
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

then you have to implement your form validations in your class file. like below code.

```
import { Component, Inject, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

import { MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from "@angular/material/dialog";;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-example-dialog',
  templateUrl: 'example-dialog.component.html',
})
export class ExampleDialogComponent {

  ngOnInit() {

  }

bidForm = new FormGroup({
inputQuantity: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
inputPrice: new FormControl('', [Validators.required])
 });

  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ExampleDialogComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) { }


  onNoClick(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }


}
```

Then Your template should be something like below

```
<form [formGroup]="bidForm">
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="inputQuantity">Quantity</label>
        <input [formControl]="inputQuantity"
          type="number"
          name="quantity"
          class="form-control"
          id="inputQuantity"
          placeholder="Quantity(QTL)*"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="inputPrice">Price</label>
        <input [formControl]="inputPrice"
          type="number"
          class="form-control"
          id="inputPrice"
          placeholder="Price(₹/QTL)"
          required
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  
    <button
      type="submit"
      class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"
      [disabled]="!bidForm.form.valid"
    >
      Send offer
    </button>
  </form>
```

You can't copy/paste these codes and run your app. this is an example with required changes. note imports, form groups and form controls in the class file and template file. You can adjust this code for your requirement. Please refer angular Reactive Forms.